# SQL Count. How can I count how many distinct values are in a table when an other two columns are matching?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct, multiple-columns

I am trying to complete an sql query to show how many GCSEs a student has on record.]

```
    *STUDENT         *SUBJECT                                     *SCHOOL
    ABB13778 |  English                                   | Social Care & Early Years
    ABB13778 |  Information and Communication Technology  | Social Care & Early Years
    ABB13778 |  Mathematics                               | Social Care & Early Years
    ABB13778 |  Media Studies                             | Social Care & Early Years
```

For example this student should recieve a count of 4 as there is 4 distinct subjects assigned to the school and student ID.

I can count the items but the output should be by school and number(see below), and I am not sure how toy form a case to create this

```
                               NUM OF STUDENT with each amount of GCSE
   SCHOOL                      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11

   Social Care & Early Years | 5   1   2   7   0   1   13  15  8   4     2
   Built Environment         |
   Business & Computing      |
```

This is probably simpler than I am thinking but at the minute I cant get my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192330/select-countdistinct-value-returns-1?rq=1

Comment: So you need the count for each student and then you want to know how many students have a given count (1 to ...) for each school? Did you want this in one SQL query?

Comment: Yes. it can be in a few query's but as it come from a large database it needs to be formatted in the query as it would be an extensive task. I can pull the data easily but its not in the format that I need @RayHenry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After grouping the data by school and student, you need to then run it through a `PIVOT` on the count of Students with each number of subjects, to get the histogram 'bins':

```
SELECT [School], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11]
FROM
(
   SELECT School, Student, COUNT([Subject]) AS Subjects
   FROM Student_GCSE
   GROUP BY School, Student
) x
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(Student)
  FOR Subjects IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11])
) y;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4660/1)

I've assumed a finite number of subjects, but you can derive the columns as well using [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902703/314291)

Comment: +1 : Though this (by the nature of pivoted data) does assume that no-one has 12 or more GCSEs.

Comment: Yup, doing this dynamically is quite straightforward - added a link.

Comment: Depends on your definition of `straightforward` ;)  Personally I always shudder at that code, too messy, and push pivoting to the application.

Comment: There is an error coming up saying the syntax is incorrect after x. This should work though my version of sql server management is 2005. would this be an issue.

Comment: Hmm ... I've just run this on `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5324.00 (X64)`. Possibly related to your actual table / column names?

Comment: Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the stored procedure sp_dbcmptlevel.... Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: You're probably running Sql 2000 compatability - Ouch. If you have access to do so, back up your DB and head over to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794.aspx). Sql 2005 is compatability level 90.

Comment: I wont be able to do that on the work computer. extremely important database so a bit too risky. Looking at your sql fiddle this method is perfect... wish i could use it :(

Comment: You might try and [make the case that Sql2005 is at the end of its lifespan](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cdnitmanagers/archive/2012/12/06/sql-server-2000-end-of-support-april-2013.aspx) and it may be time to upgrade?

Comment: work in a college.. we have talked about it but no funds available at present. But in our work these pivots could be so useful so I will have a word in someones ear.

Answer (score 1):

`Group by` should solve this, Something like following:

```
select SCHOOL, subject, count(*) as NUM_STUDENTS from records
group by STUDENT, SCHOOL;
```

Comment: This pulls the correct data but not in the format that I need to display it.

Answer (score 1):

Now, I don't use SQL Server and I don't have a SQL command line handy, but have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT SCHOOL, N, COUNT(STUDENT) 
FROM (SELECT SCHOOL, STUDENT, COUNT(DISTINCT SUBJECT) AS N 
FROM MY_TABLE GROUP BY SCHOOL, STUDENT) GROUP BY SCHOOL, N;
```

Comment: +1 : Although this doesn't pivot the data as the OP requested, it's normalised structure does mean that it *does* handle students with more than 11 GCSEs.  The pivoting is better suited to the presentation layer of an application than the sql layer.